# SQL SELECT the rows with the first activity of each day for each person using time

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select, time

I have a table that contains data for timed activities for multiple employees. From this table, I need to select only the row where the activity is the first activity of the day for a given sa_person using [day] (date) and [time] columns.
The [activity id] column is not reliable for the sequence of events as some of the date/times are entered manually out of sequence.

Below are images of the starting table and desired result.

Thank You in advance for any help!

**Table Structure:**

[image: Table Structure]

**Desired Result:**

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: a .csv with an extended data sample added here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ajnifyt76ca9ifg/Sample.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query as below:

```
Select * from (
   Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over (partition by saperson, [Day] order by [time] asc) from yourtable ) a
Where a.RowN = 1
```

It is always better to provide data with text so that we can check the data...

you can use top (1) with ties as well

```
Select top(1) with ties * from yourtable
Order by Row_Number() over (partition by saperson, [Day] order by [time])
```

Comment: `desc`?  Do you mean `asc`? "...is the ***first*** activity of the day for a given sa_person..."

Comment: Yep first [time] entry i removed that desc... Thanks

Comment: Thank You for the quick responses. I have added a link above with extended data in csv format.